# grep list invert

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, zsh

How can I print a filename if the file doesn't contain a string?

```
grep -vl 'string' file
```

always prints `file`, I guess because there is at least one line per file that isn't `string`.

```
$ ls
one  two  three  four  five
$ grep -l 'odd' *
one
three
five
$ grep -lv 'odd' *
one
two
three
four
five
```

But I want it to print the inverse of the first option

```
two
four
```

Comment: The answer was `grep -L ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`grep` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/General-Output-Control.html#General-Output-Control):

> `-L` 
> `--files-without-match`
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed. The scanning of each file stops on the first match.

So, you need to use

```sh
grep -L 'odd' *
four
two
```